# Changing CSS Styles for component

Tags: joomla

I am using Joomla Membership Pro component and am having some trouble with CSS styling.

If you click here

http://se24media.net/dc3/index.php/join-us/membership-options/supporter/sign-up

You will see the background is styled nicely but if you fill in the form, click submit and go through to the page which dispalys your membership details it loses all styling (see link below)

http://i60.tinypic.com/33pa4c2.png

Does anyone know why it suddenly loses it's formatting?

Many thanks

Comment: This page is probably better to look at rather than fill the form out

http://www.se24media.net/dc3/index.php/component/users/?view=reset

Answer (score 0):

It loses the styling because on the first page, the table containing all the fields is wrapped with `<form>` tags like so:

```
<form id="os_form">
    <!-- Table with fields are in here -->
</form>
```

and the following CSS has been given for `#os_form`

```
#os_form {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url("/dc3/images/news_header.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #868687;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 3px 0;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro',sans-serif;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 40px 40px 50px;
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 40px 20px 20px;
    width: 85%;
}
```

The second page simply displays a table with the class `os_table` so style this table, you will need to add the following to your CSS file:

```
.os_table {
    /* code here */
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you does this go in the components/com_membership/assets/css/style.css?

This is what i have added to that file

`code`#os_table {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url("/dc3/images/news_header.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #868687;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 3px 0;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro',sans-serif;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 40px 40px 50px;
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 40px 20px 20px;
    width: 85%;
}`code`

Comment: Personally I **wouldn't** add it to `assets/css/style.css` because if you ever install an update for this extension, it will override your changes. I would suggest adding it to your template css file as an template override is not possible in your case.